# MacOS install pycairo

Tags: macos, python

When I try to install pycairo on my mac (10.14.2 Beta), I get the following error.

Can someone help troubleshoot?

I ran `pip3 install pycairo`, but I got an error when setup.py was run for pycairo.

I have cairo installed, but when I run cairo in the terminal, it tells me that the command isn't found.

[image: logs from cairo install]

Comment: I thought I attached a picture! Edited.

Comment: I already had cairo installed via brew, version 1.16.0.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the same error here with `brew`'s `cairo`. Perhaps you should file a bug report with Homebrew or `pycairo`?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it seems that you haven't installed `cairo` before, which it seems to be needed to run `pycairo`.

Please try `brew install cairo` and then try to run `pip install pycairo`.

If you run into the same problem that I did, and still find errors in installing `pycairo` due to a missing `libffi` packaged, I found that following the solutions [here](https://github.com/googlefonts/gftools/issues/121#issuecomment-490666998) solved my issue. Briefly, I reinstalled `libffi`, added the path to `libffi.pc` to `PATH`, and then tried reinstalling pycairo in a new terminal session.